# Eliminate mismatch between two GeoTIFF satellite images

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, remote-sensing

I have two GeoTIFF satellite images of the same area made on different dates (both are in the same CRS). When I open the images in QGIS, I can see that objects (buildings, etc.) have slightly different coordinates (e.g., a building can be about 20 meters apart from the same building on the other image).

How can I change one of the images to minimize that distance?

I am probably looking for a library that can match the images automatically and shift one of them, or for a tool where it can be done manually (shifting an image and matching objects on both images).

Since the error/shift is different in different parts of the image, I am thinking about splitting both images into tiles and then aligning them tile by tile, so some sort of automated way of doing it would be preferred.

**UPDATE:**

This is not a duplicate question because it is about matching two satellite images of the same area which (at least in theory) can be achieved with, say, a library using a machine learning based solution.

The other question is about matching a vector layer (a shape file) and a satellite image. I do not expect any fully automated solution there. In case of a manual solution, it probably goiong to be a different tool/approach.

Comment: Twenty meters sounds about right. Georeferencing is a difficult task, and getting *every* object perfect is impossible.  This is a *huge* task, probably not a quick SE-style problem-solving issue.

Comment: Reopened. If you very similar questions, from the beginning mention the difference between both and make a link to the other post. So people answering one question might get an idea from the other question.

Comment: The distance between the same object on the two images can be about 30 pixels. There should be some way to rid of it if I cut the image to small tiles (so that the distance inside a tile does not vary much).

Comment: You can align images using OpenCV but you would need a solution to rebuild the spatial portions of your geotiff.  https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.